# Mapping a POJO to a table dynamically in hibernate using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dynamic, hibernate-mapping

In my DB, I have around 20+ of tables named like 'a_emp_transactions', 'b_emp_transaction' and so on where the table structure was same for all the tables. Basically these tables are divided based on the name of the employee.

Now I want to do CURD operations on those tables using hibernate, but I don't want to create POJO for each and every table. Since, only the name of the table is different and has same structure, is there any way to use single POJO and map that POJO to the table dynamically based on the current employee name using annotations?

Comment: An annotation is about as far from dynamic as you can get, fixed at compile time.

Comment: The question is whether he can reuse is annotation-mapped POJO for diffrent database tables. "Dynamically" refers to to the process of finding the correct table, not dynamic annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a big flaw in your DB architecture.
Why using 20+ tables when you might use ONE with the same fields + an "EmployeeName/ID" field?

In that way you would be able to map a POJO to a single table, and IMHO it would be a far more consistent architecture.

Comment: For each employee there may be hundreds of transactions per week and there are more than 1000 employees. So to make the DB operations fast the architecture was like that. Any way there is no chance of changing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate Shards to accomplish that. Basically, Hibernate Shards allows you to specify a "sharding" strategy. It can be distribution of data accross different database servers or just separate tables (as it seems it's your case). You certainly will want to create a strategy of your own, as I don't believe the existing examples will cover your case perfectly :-)

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/shards/reference/en/html/shards-shardstrategy.html

By the way: I'm not sure if Hibernate Shards will allow you to change the table name of a mapped entity (perhaps it's possible, I just don't know). In any case: if it's not possible, you can probably create different Hibernate Naming Strategies, and use each shard with a different naming strategy.